# Prism - Unity - Can't resolve IRegionBehaviorFactory in ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

i'm new to Prism, i have an application and i need to have a custom region mapping.

when i try to resolve IRegionBehaviorFactory with ServiceLocator, i receive the error :

> Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type IRegionBehaviorFactory, key ""

I understand that is because the class RegionBehaviorFactory receive Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IServiceLocator, but with Unity 7.0 i use as ServiceLocator Unity.ServiceLocation.UnityServiceLocator

How can i do?
This is my bootstrapper.cs

```
 class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    private UnityContainer uc = new UnityContainer();

    protected override void ConfigureServiceLocator()
    {
        base.ConfigureServiceLocator();

        UnityServiceLocator locator = new UnityServiceLocator(uc);

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
    }


    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<wMain>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (wMain)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
    }

    protected override void InitializeModules()
    {
        base.InitializeModules();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        uc.RegisterType<IServiceLocator, UnityServiceLocator>();
        uc.RegisterType<IRegionBehaviorFactory,  RegionBehaviorFactory>();

        Application.Current.Resources.Add("IoC", uc);
    }

    protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
    {
        var mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();

        var aa = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionBehaviorFactory>();

        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(RadPaneGroup), new RadPaneGroupRegionAdapter(uc.Resolve<RegionBehaviorFactory>()));

        return mappings;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating anew container and service locator?  That class is all wrong. You don't need to create those as the container with all services has already been created for you. That's why you're using the UnityBootstrapper. The ServiceLocator is also already setup for you.

You should go through these samples to better understand hwo to use Prism: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf

Another bit of advice, don't use the ServiceLocator like you are. That's bad practice.  Stick with common DI patterns and resolve objects usin ctor injectin or by resolving objects from your container.